# Flutter redux keeps refreshing widget even not in current page

Tags: flutter, redux

Hi I am using Flutter + Redux in my app and current have a performance issue.

I have two pages controlled by routing. Both pages are listening to some variables in the redux store. When app is started, page A is shown and page B is not being refreshed. After showing page B and then switching page A, widgets in page B keep being refreshed.

Is there anyway in Flutter or redux can prevent page B being refreshed when it is not shown. Thanks